# Infer one type parameter, but not the other?

Tags: scala, generics

Here is my use case:

```
 def mkWrapper[A,B](doer: StuffDoer[B])(implicit ev: A => B) = 
    new StuffDoer[A] {
       override def doStuff(a: A) = doer.doStuff(ev(a))
    }
```

Now, suppose I have an instance of

`StuffDoer[AwfullyLong[Complicated,And],_ <: Difficult[ToRead],Type]`

defined somewhere, and an implicit conversion from `String` to ... well, *that* type.

I am looking for suggestions of how I can call `mkWrapper[String,_](doer)`, and have it infer its second type parameter from the type of `doer` rather than having to spell it out.

Ideas?

Comment: This may or may not help: https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/07/30/infer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution for this problem is to create a new class with

- the type parameter you do want to specify and
- an `apply` method with the rest of the type parameters.

Some examples in [cats](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/data/Coproduct.scala#L93-L103) (`Coproduct.left[X]`) and [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/syntax/hlists.scala#L198-L202) (the `*Aux` syntax helper classes).

In your case this could look like :

```
class WrapperHelper[A] {
  def apply[B](doer: StuffDoer[B])(implicit ev: A => B) = 
    new StuffDoer[A] {
       override def doStuff(a: A) = doer.doStuff(ev(a))
    }
}

def mkWrapper[A] = new WrapperHelper[A]
```

You end up with something which looks like one function call, when there are actually two :

```
val stuff: StuffDoer[Int] = ???
mkWrapper[Double](stuff)
mkWrapper[Double].apply(stuff)
```

This is the same trick Rob Norris explains on the page @m-z linked to in his comment.

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, except for one complication I did not mention in the original post: the `mkWrapper` signature actually looks like `mkWrapper[A : Manifest, B]`, so I have to carry the `Manifest` thingy, and now, when I write `mkWrapper[Double](stuff)`, it wants `stuff` to be `Manifest` :( I can write `mkWrapper[Double].apply(stuff)`, which is still an improvement, but the perfectionist in me isn't happy :( 
Any ideas how to get around that?

Comment: @Dima It seems that in this case you could add an extra implicit `man:  Manifest[A]` to the `apply` function (and remove the  `: Manifest` context bound from `mkWrapper`), but it is not always possible to move the implicit parameters.